# SVD to solve harwell-boeing sparse a.x=b system in C/C++?

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, numerical-methods, svd

Does anybody know of a sparse SVD solver for c++? My problem involves some badly conditioned matrices that might have zeroed columns/rows. My data is stored in a uBLAS matrix which is the Harwell-Boeing sparse format.

I am having some trouble finding:

The SVD solver

1. The SVD solver that can operate on sparse matrices. Lapack doesn't seem to be able to do this? I want to have sparse matrices passed to the function and sparse matrices output.
2. A way to recombine the results... So that I can read off the xs from x=b(A^-1). I would expect this to be x=(b)(v.(d^-1).(u^t))

I am hoping to recreate the following two steps from GSL

```
gsl_linalg_SV_decomp_jacobi (gsl_matrix * A, gsl_matrix * V, gsl_vector * S) 
gsl_linalg_SV_solve (const gsl_matrix * U, const gsl_matrix * V, const gsl_vector * S, const gsl_vector * b, gsl_vector * x)
```

I also have no clue how to wrap a FORTRAN library in c++.
Where/Are there any PROPACK c/c++ bindings?

Edit 1:
I'm having some trouble with PROPACK. Does PROPACK output sparse matrices? It seems to output V as "V(LDV,KMAX): DOUBLE PRECISION array." which would imply that it doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SVDLIBC](http://tedlab.mit.edu/~dr/SVDLIBC/) is a C library with [partial support for the Harwell-Boeing](http://tedlab.mit.edu/~dr/SVDLIBC/SVD_F_STH.html) format. I am not familiar with the library, but on the surface it seems to match your requirements.

Comment: Closest thing to what I wanted. Although I don't know if it will actually work!

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned [PROPACK](http://soi.stanford.edu/~rmunk/PROPACK/).  Fortran is C-compatible, you just have to know how the calling convention works.  I'm not certain, but I think that the function you want to call in PROPACK is `dlansvd` (assuming double-precision), which is documented as follows:

```
  subroutine dlansvd(jobu,jobv,m,n,k,kmax,aprod,U,ldu,Sigma,bnd,
 c     V,ldv,tolin,work,lwork,iwork,liwork,doption,ioption,info,
 c     dparm,iparm)


c     DLANSVD: Compute the leading singular triplets of a large and
c     sparse matrix by Lanczos bidiagonalization with partial
c     reorthogonalization.
c
c     Parameters:
c
c     JOBU: CHARACTER*1. If JOBU.EQ.'Y' then compute the left singular vectors.
c     JOBV: CHARACTER*1. If JOBV.EQ.'Y' then compute the right singular 
c           vectors.
c     M: INTEGER. Number of rows of A.
c     N: INTEGER. Number of columns of A.
c     K: INTEGER. Number of desired singular triplets. K <= MIN(KMAX,M,N)
c     KMAX: INTEGER. Maximal number of iterations = maximal dimension of
c           the generated Krylov subspace.
c     APROD: Subroutine defining the linear operator A. 
c            APROD should be of the form:
c
c           SUBROUTINE DAPROD(TRANSA,M,N,X,Y,DPARM,IPARM)
c           CHARACTER*1 TRANSA
c           INTEGER M,N,IPARM(*)
c           DOUBLE PRECISION X(*),Y(*),DPARM(*)
c
c           If TRANSA.EQ.'N' then the function should compute the matrix-vector
c           product Y = A * X.
c           If TRANSA.EQ.'T' then the function should compute the matrix-vector
c           product Y = A^T * X.
c           The arrays IPARM and DPARM are a means to pass user supplied
c           data to APROD without the use of common blocks.
c     U(LDU,KMAX+1): DOUBLE PRECISION array. On return the first K columns of U
c               will contain approximations to the left singular vectors 
c               corresponding to the K largest singular values of A.
c               On entry the first column of U contains the starting vector
c               for the Lanczos bidiagonalization. A random starting vector
c               is used if U is zero.
c     LDU: INTEGER. Leading dimension of the array U. LDU >= M.
c     SIGMA(K): DOUBLE PRECISION array. On return Sigma contains approximation
c               to the K largest singular values of A.
c     BND(K)  : DOUBLE PRECISION array. Error estimates on the computed 
c               singular values. The computed SIGMA(I) is within BND(I)
c               of a singular value of A.
c     V(LDV,KMAX): DOUBLE PRECISION array. On return the first K columns of V
c               will contain approximations to the right singular vectors 
c               corresponding to the K largest singular values of A.
c     LDV: INTEGER. Leading dimension of the array V. LDV >= N.
c     TOLIN: DOUBLE PRECISION. Desired relative accuracy of computed singular 
c            values. The error of SIGMA(I) is approximately 
c            MAX( 16*EPS*SIGMA(1), TOLIN*SIGMA(I) )
c     WORK(LWORK): DOUBLE PRECISION array. Workspace of dimension LWORK.
c     LWORK: INTEGER. Dimension of WORK.
c            If JOBU.EQ.'N' and JOBV.EQ.'N' then  LWORK should be at least
c            M + N + 9*KMAX + 2*KMAX**2 + 4 + MAX(M+N,4*KMAX+4).
c            If JOBU.EQ.'Y' or JOBV.EQ.'Y' then LWORK should be at least
c            M + N + 9*KMAX + 5*KMAX**2 + 4 + 
c            MAX(3*KMAX**2+4*KMAX+4, NB*MAX(M,N)), where NB>1 is a block 
c            size, which determines how large a fraction of the work in
c            setting up the singular vectors is done using fast BLAS-3 
c            operation. 
c     IWORK: INTEGER array. Integer workspace of dimension LIWORK.
c     LIWORK: INTEGER. Dimension of IWORK. Should be at least 8*KMAX if
c             JOBU.EQ.'Y' or JOBV.EQ.'Y' and at least 2*KMAX+1 otherwise.
c     DOPTION: DOUBLE PRECISION array. Parameters for LANBPRO.
c        doption(1) = delta. Level of orthogonality to maintain among
c          Lanczos vectors.
c        doption(2) = eta. During reorthogonalization, all vectors with
c          with components larger than eta along the latest Lanczos vector
c          will be purged.
c        doption(3) = anorm. Estimate of || A ||.
c     IOPTION: INTEGER array. Parameters for LANBPRO.
c        ioption(1) = CGS.  If CGS.EQ.1 then reorthogonalization is done
c          using iterated classical GRAM-SCHMIDT. IF CGS.EQ.0 then 
c          reorthogonalization is done using iterated modified Gram-Schmidt.
c        ioption(2) = ELR. If ELR.EQ.1 then extended local orthogonality is
c          enforced among u_{k}, u_{k+1} and v_{k} and v_{k+1} respectively.
c     INFO: INTEGER. 
c         INFO = 0  : The K largest singular triplets were computed succesfully
c         INFO = J>0, J<K: An invariant subspace of dimension J was found.
c         INFO = -1 : K singular triplets did not converge within KMAX
c                     iterations.   
c     DPARM: DOUBLE PRECISION array. Array used for passing data to the APROD
c         function.   
c     IPARM: INTEGER array. Array used for passing data to the APROD
c         function.   
c
c     (C) Rasmus Munk Larsen, Stanford, 1999, 2004 
c
```

In Fortran, the important things to remember is that all parameters are passed *by reference*, and non-sparse arrays are stored in *column-major* format.  So, the proper declaration of this function in C++ should be as follows (untested):

```
extern "C"
void dlansvd(const char *jobu,
             const char *jobv,
             int *m,
             int *n,
             int *k,
             int *kmax,
             void (*aprod)(const char *transa,
                           int *m,
                           int *n,
                           int *iparm,
                           double *x,
                           double *y,
                           double *dparm),
             double *U,
             int *ldu,
             double *Sigma,
             double *bnd,
             double *V,
             int *ldv,
             double *tolin,
             double *work,
             int *lwork,
             int *iwork,
             int *liwork,
             double *doption,
             int *ioption,
             int *info,
             double *dparm,
             int *iparm);
```

It's quite a beast.  Good luck!

Comment: I'm currently investigating this route: although its not at all the direction I wanted to go :-). There is a small typo: should say double *V, int *ldv... (v not u)

Comment: This outputs dense (non-sparse) arrays? Is there one that supports sparse arrays? My matrix A would be at least 10000x10000+ units wide...

Answer (score 0):

It might be worthwhile checking out Tim Davis's sparse linear algebra software: http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~davis/

Generally speaking I've found his software to be really useful, typically very efficient and robust.

It seems that he's been working on a sparse SVD package with a student, but I'm not sure what stage the project is at.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Misha: If you follow the link to his site, find "current students" and have a look into the project about sparse SVD. Based on my very quick look, it seems that you may be able to get access to the code if you send an email...